# java : how can i use if correctly

Tags: java

I recently started java programming

but I have a problem
i want to write a program. I have a password, I ask the user of the program to enter the password
I want: if the person entered a string, I tell him that please don't enter string
and if the password was right and the type of the password that he entered(int) was right, I tell him OK.

in the test of the program, my problem is that when I entered a wrong password and expect that the program tell me that the pass is wrong, the program just tell me nothing !!

here is my code :

```
    int pass = 123 ;

    Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Password : ");


    if (password.hasNextInt() && password.nextInt()==pass)
    {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else if (password.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        System.out.println("wrong pass");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("wrong type");
    }
```

Comment: What is `pass`?

Comment: You should debug your program and then update your question based on your findings.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `hasNextInt()` From Java docs.

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as an int value

So you are asking twice for the input. 
Example

```
Input:
1234 (first Input)
1234 (Then hasNextInt() is asking for input again)
OutPut :

wrong pass
```

So I made this simple snippet for you can use

```
Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter Your Password : ");
int pass = 123;
try {
   int myInput = password.nextInt();
   if (myInput == pass) {
       System.out.println("ok");
   }else{
       System.out.println("wrong pass");
   }
}catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
     System.out.println("wrong type");
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working for non-integer values for e.g. :
Please Enter Your Password : 
test
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: This exception block is redundant:
 `try{

}catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("wrong type");
}`

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick You are correct my bad editing right now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Scanner` methods like `nextInt()` consume input that's then no longer available to later `Scanner` calls.

```
int pass = 123 ;

Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter Your Password : ");


if (password.hasNextInt() && password.nextInt()==pass)  // line A
{
    System.out.println("ok");
}
else if (password.hasNextInt())                         // line B
{
    System.out.println("wrong pass");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("wrong type");
}
```

So in case of entering a wrong password, e.g. 4321, what happens?

- Line A checks `password.hasNextInt()` as the first half of your condition. The `Scanner` doesn't know that right now and waits for your console input. You enter `4321`, and now the `Scanner` can check whether that's a valid number (and it does so without consuming the `4321`, so that it's still available). It is, so the program continues to the next part of the condition (side remark: were it `abc`, that first part would be false, and Java would already know that the combined `password.hasNextInt() && password.nextInt()==pass` condition would be false, without a need to go into the second half, thus not consuming the entry).
- Line A now checks the second half `password.nextInt()==pass`. This calls `nextInt()`, returning the integer `4321` and **consuming the input**. Comparing this against your number `123` gives false, so the condition doesn't match. That's what you want so far.
- Now in line B you want to check for the case of a number not being `123`. But your condition `password.hasNextInt()` no longer sees the `4321` we entered, as that has been consumed in line A. **So it waits for the next input.** That's the problem, you're still calling `hasNextInt()` **after** consuming the input with `nextInt()`.

You can change your program like this:

```
int pass = 123 ;

Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter Your Password : ");

if (password.hasNextInt()) {
    if (password.nextInt()==pass) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong pass");
    }
} else {
    pass.next();      // consume the invalid entry 
    System.out.println("wrong type");
}
```

[ I reformatted the code snippet in a more Java-typical style, doesn't change the functionality of course, but looks more familiar to me. ]

Of course, Gatusko's exception-based approach works as well, and personally I'd do it his way, but maybe you don't feel comfortable with exceptions right now, so I stayed as close to your approach as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, if the input is not an integer then it will throw `NumberFormatException`, which is caught and displayed.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int pass = 123 ;
        Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Password : ");
        String enteredPassword ="";
        if(password.hasNext() && (enteredPassword = password.next()) !=null){
            try{
                if(Integer.parseInt(enteredPassword) == pass){
                    System.out.println("ok");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("wrong pass");
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                System.out.println("wrong type");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int pass = 123 ;

        Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Password : ");


        if (password.hasNextInt())
        {
            if(password.nextInt()==pass) {
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Wrong password");
            }
        }


        else
        {
            System.out.println("wrong type");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a while?

```
int MAX_TRIES = 3

int currentTries = 0;
    while (password.hasNextInt() && currentTries < MAX_TRIES) {
        if (password.nextInt()==pass) {
            // OK!
        } else {
            // Wrong!
        }
        currentTries++;
    }

    if (currentTries == MAX_TRIES) {
        // You tried too much
    } else {
        // Password was a string
    }
```